# SOQL - How to obtain Parent Name of CombinedAttachments

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am unable to obtain the Name of a Parent object, where the child is CombinedAttachments.
The SOQL I use is listed below and works as expected.

> SELECT  ( SELECT Id, Title, RecordType, LastModifiedDate,
>   CreatedBy.Name, ParentId  from CombinedAttachments    WHERE  ParentId
>   = '001b0000009ovxS'       ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC limit 100  )  FROM Account WHERE Id = '001b0000009ovxS'

What is impossible is to add a filed like Parent.Name or Parent.Account.Name.
However, in other cases of Parent-Child queries like that, it is straightforward to refer to Parent fields by using dot notation like Parent.CaseNumber or Who.Name
It seems that due to the fact that there may be multiple references possible in ParentID (Account,Asset,Campaign,Case,Contact,Contract,EmailTemplate,Event,Lead,Opportunity,Product2,Solution,Task)

Comment: One idea sparked by the answer below is to use the Parent name in the Parent Query, but NOT using the IN operator, but actually use the syntax above.

Answer (score 0):

With a polymorphic relationship field, such as `CombinedAttachments.ParentId`, the field can reference a large number of types.

In this case you can only select a subset of fields that are common to all the types being referenced.

You will need to do secondary queries to Account to pull the required fields.

Alternatively, you might be able to reverse the join to get the Account fields, but you have now lost the CombinedAttachments fields.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (Select ParentID from CombinedAttachments)
```

As an aside, there is a dedicated [Salesforce StackExchange site](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) for Salesforce questions.

Comment: This was the a step in the right direction, that failed when ran for a non-Admin profile with some security issue. The trick was to remove the internal "WHERE", as it is redundant logic (based on how embedded SOQL works). Bottom line, the above syntax works fine (make sure NOT to include internal redundant WHERE).

Answer (score 0):

One tested approach is to use the Parent field name in the parent side rather then refer to it from the sub-query:

> SELECT Name, Id, ( SELECT Id, Title, RecordType, LastModifiedDate,
>   CreatedBy.Name, ParentId from CombinedAttachments WHERE ParentId =
>   '001b0000009ovxS' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC limit 100 ) FROM
>   Account WHERE Id = '001b0000009ovxS'